# Why my connected state doesn't update, when I call an action from componentWillMount()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My problem is, that I have a container, which was loaded before and mounted again, doesn't update it's connected state after the state was updated via an action from `componentWillMount()`.

Here the code from the container (you can get all the full code [here](https://github.com/openscript/webquote/blob/11f630f2ead04b35569541206af82da5955d54d6/src/actions/quote.ts)):

```
// [...]

interface Params {
    method: 'from-definition'|'from-saved';
    target: string;
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<Params> {
    state: State;
    actions: typeof Actions;
}

interface ContainerState {
    isActionBarSticky: boolean;
}

class Container extends React.Component<Props, ContainerState> {
    private isTicking: boolean;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isActionBarSticky: true,
        };

        // [...]
    }

    public componentWillMount() {
        switch (this.props.match.params.method) {
            case 'from-definition':
                this.props.actions.setQuoteFromDefinitionName(this.props.match.params.target);
                break;
            case 'from-saved':
                this.props.actions.setQuoteFromSavedQuoteTitle(this.props.match.params.target);
                break;
        }
    }

    // [...]

    public render() {
        // [...]

        if (this.props.state.quote) {
            loadedQuote = this.props.state.quote.sections.map((s) => {
                return (
                    // [...]
                );
            });
            // [...]
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper style={this.state.isActionBarSticky ? {paddingBottom: '56px'} : undefined}>
                {loadedQuote}
                {actionBar}
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }

    // [...]
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
    state,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<State>) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators<typeof Actions>(Actions, dispatch)
});

export const QuoteContainer = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container));
```

So the container was loaded before and I visit the same page again, so it's mounted again. `this.props.actions.setQuoteFromDefinitionName(this.props.match.params.target);` is called.

As I see in the Redux DevTools it updates the state correctly.

[image: ReduxDev]

The container renders after `componentWillMount()` as expected, but the state in `this.props.state.quote` isn't updated. Why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From react docs: componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.

Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering.